# Why ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'key', after pip install key successful?

Tags: python, api, module, jupyter-notebook

[Already installed 'key', why still giving error that no module 'key' found?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS3nF.png)

Comment: read note under pip install - reboot?

Comment: The problem still persists after restarting the kernel.